# Type conversion with JPA depends on another attribute in the same entity

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a table with `key`, `value` and `valueType` as columns. Value can be one of `int`, `long`, `boolean` and a `collection` all represented as a string in the db.  The collection is saved as a delimited collection. I want these to be converted appropriate types during the retrieval from database . I found the following [blog post](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html) that talks about @Covert in JPA 2.1.

But my trouble is that the type of value is stored in the `valueType` attribute. How can I introduce the `valueType` into the Converter so I can use it to decide which type it needs to be converted to ?

Comment: Can you paste the JPA entity? Curious to see what you have so far and you're trying to do. I have a feeling that you want to restrict that to sort of a enum. MySQL has that column type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the property to certain values, you can use an `enum` property and make use of an `CustomEnumConverter` class. Here's an example:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/mapping-enums-done-right.

Now, I know MySQL supports it. In SQL server you can restrict values by:

```
mycol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (mycol IN('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))
```

Comment: The value itself is not restricted, so I don't think this solution will work. Thankyou though.

Comment: If it is not restricted, that is a relation to another table, right? so you'd have the id property of that other class/table within this entity as a foreign key.